# Davinci Resolve 16 won't start in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, dell

I installed DaVinci Resolve 16 on Ubuntu 18.04 using makeresolvedeb. When I click on the desktop icon nothing visible happens. Here are my results of running Resolve from the command line:

```
$ /opt/resolve/bin/resolve
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
PnlMsgActionStringAdapter Already in Table: Code= 615e, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
16.0 (#060) Linux/Clang
Main thread starts: 74325B00
log4cxx: setFile(./logs/rollinglog.txt,true) call failed.
log4cxx: IO Exception : status code = 2
[0x7f6674325b00] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-08-14 16:30:25,444 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
log4cxx: No output stream or file set for the appender named [RollLogAppender].
[0x7f6674325b00] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-08-14 16:30:25,444 | Loaded log config from /home/claude/.local/share/DaVinciResolve/configs/log-conf.xml
[0x7f6674325b00] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-08-14 16:30:25,444 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem. I'm familiar with with the command line but am a novice not a wizard.

I am running a Dell Inspiron 15R (Core i7, 5537)

Many Thanks!

Comment: I get exactly the same issue trying to install DaVinci Resolve 16.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 running on ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th gen.

Comment: No solution came through for this?

Answer (score 4):

Did you do it along these lines?

Installed the packages libssl1.0.0, ocl-icd-opencl-dev, fakeroot and xorriso (the first two packages are needed for running DaVinci Resolve and the last 2 packages for generating the deb).

1. sudo apt install libssl1.0.0 ocl-icd-opencl-dev fakeroot xorriso
2. Download the latest DaVinci Resolve 16 for Linux and extract it in your home folder (scroll down to the end of the page for the download button).
3. Download The MakeResolveDeb script (http://www.danieltufvesson.com/makeresolvedeb) and extract it in the same folder where you extracted DaVinci Resolve 16.

   - Make sure the DaVinci Resolve and the MakeResolveDeb script are the exact same version.
   - Make sure both the DaVinci Resolve and the MakeResolveDeb scripts (the extracted .sh files) are in the same folder.
4. Run the MakeResolveDeb script to create the DaVinci Resolve 16.

Assuming you've extracted DaVinci Resolve in your home folder and placed the MakeResolveDeb script in the same folder as DaVinci Resolve, you can create the deb by using these commands:

- cd ~/DaVinci_Resolve*_Linux
- ./makeresolvedeb*.sh lite
- "*" is in the commands because of the version changes, so check the version.
- The lite option in command is for the regular, free DaVinci Resolve 16.

Accept the DaVinci Resolve license typing y and press Enter

5. Now you can hopefully install the DaVinci Resolve 16 or 15.3 deb using Software or Gdebi (and launch).

Comment: Thank you Neoncode. That is exactly what I did. I unfortunately I get the error noted above.

Comment: Did same steps. Getting the op error too. I just feel DR people just don't want other distros to use it.